# Trouble installing rgbif package in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I was trying to install rgbif package on R using install.package() and I ran into a few errors. The code is given below

```
> install.packages("rgbif")
Installing package into ‘/home/djokester/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘V8’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/V8_1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 325718 bytes (318 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 318 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rgbif_0.9.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 684603 bytes (668 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 668 KB

* installing *source* package ‘V8’ ...
** package ‘V8’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/v8-3.14
Using PKG_LIBS=-lv8
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because  was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libv8-3.14-dev (formerly: libv8-dev) (Debian, Ubuntu)
 * rpm: v8-314-devel (formerly: v8-devel) (Fedora, EPEL)
 * brew: v8-315 (OSX) -- NOT regular v8! Tap from homebrew/versions
 * csw: libv8_dev (Solaris)
To use a custom libv8, set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘V8’
* removing ‘/home/djokester/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/V8’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘V8’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘V8’ is not available for package ‘rgbif’
* removing ‘/home/djokester/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rgbif’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgbif’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpCJKNuX/downloaded_packages’
```

I am trying to install rgbif package on Ubuntu 16.10. There are some errors. Can someone help me with the install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you that you are missing the Ubuntu package `libv8-dev`:

> Configuration failed because  was not found. Try installing:
>
> - deb: libv8-3.14-dev (formerly: libv8-dev) (Debian, Ubuntu)

To install it, run the following on the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install libv8-3.14-dev
```

Or install `libv8-3.14-dev` with Synaptic. Afterwards you should be able to install `rgbif` in R with `install.packages("rgbif")`.